# Cron job suddenly not running php script?

Tags: php, linux, bash, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi and cron jobs running bash scripts which run scripts in a PHP file.

They've been working fine for months, but cron now refuses to run two of them (see code of one of the bash scripts below). Getting cron to run the php scripts directly isn't working either.

Any ideas as to what can be wrong? I've tried all sorts but can't get cron to co-operate any more with these two scripts!

Example code of bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#<<END_SCRIPT
wget http://192.168.0.9/min.php -q
#END_SCRIPT
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does it sayin the syslog?

Comment: The script itself is running fine?

Comment: Why do you use wget instead of cURL?

Comment: marcolz - Syslog says "CRON[31090]: (root) CMD (sh /etc/min.sh)", which implies it ran fine.

@kerbholz - Yes it runs fine when I run it manually.

Yvan Watchman - It's just the method I originally used. It usually works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

In cron expression at the end redirect stderr to file and see the error. Good Luck!